# Is There a Connection Between Minimum $ {L}_{1} $ Norm Solution and LASSO?

Tags: statistics, optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, sparsity

I am reading a book about sparsity [Statistical Learning with Sparsity:
The Lasso and Generalizations](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/StatLearnSparsity/). I want to know the relationship between the following two optimization problem: $$\min_{\beta} \| \beta\|_{1} \;  s.t. X\beta=y$$ and $$\arg \min_{\beta}  \frac{1}{2n}\|X\beta-y \|_{2}^{2}+\lambda \| \beta\|_{1}$$where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$, $y\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\beta \in\mathbb{R}^{d}$, d>n and $\lambda > 0$.

Can we say that Lasso is the relaxed version of the minimum $L_{1}$ norm solution?

Comment: It seems plausible that as $\lambda$ approaches $0$ (from the right) the solution to the second problem would approach the solution to the first problem. Hopefully someone can provide a theorem / proof to that effect.

Comment: I know that as $\lambda$ approaches $0$ the solution of ridge regression approaches the minimum $L_{2}$ norm soultion. Does this hold true for Lasso?

Comment: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/54853.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the answer in this book[High-Dimensional Statistics: A Non-Asymptotic Viewpoint](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/highdimensional-statistics/8A91ECEEC38F46DAB53E9FF8757C7A4E). In Page 206 of this book, we know that the second optimization problem is equivalent to the following optimization problem:

$$\min_{\beta} \| \beta\|_{1} \;  s.t. \frac{1}{2n} \|X\beta-y\|_{2}^{2}\leq b^{2}$$ for some noise tolerance $b>0$.

Therefore, we say that Lasso is the relaxed version with noise of the minimum $L_{1}$ norm solution.

However, if without noise, how can we adjust $\lambda$ so that the solution of the second optimization problem is equivalent to the solution of the first optimization problem???